# Can't deallocate pointer to structure previously allocated

Tags: c, memory, struct, free

I'm creating easy particle system. I've got two typedef structures. First represents single particle with some fields. Second represents system of particles. My problem is that I can't deallocate memory allocated for each Particle. Really don't know what's wrong.
Here are structures:

```
typedef struct {
   float m;  
   float *x;  
   float *v;    
   float *f;     
   float R;
} *Particle;

typedef struct {
   Particle *p;
   int n; 
   float t; 
} *ParticleSystem;
```

and here code for allocating

```
ParticleSystem sys = (ParticleSystem) malloc(sizeof(ParticleSystem));  
sys->p =  (Particle *) malloc(sizeof(Particle)*noOfParticles);

for(int i=0;i<noOfParticles;i++){
    sys->p[i] = (Particle)malloc(sizeof(Particle));

    sys->p[i]->f = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*2);
    sys->p[i]->f[0] = 0.0f;
    sys->p[i]->f[1] = 0.0f;

    ...

    sys->p[i]->R = radius;
    sys->p[i]->m = mass;

}

sys->n=noOfParticles;
sys->t = 0.0f;
```

and freeing

```
int n = sys->n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    free(sys->p[i]->f);

    ...

    free(sys->p[i]);//here it breaks
}
free(sys->p);
free(sys);
```

At line "free(sys->p[i]) it breaks. I don't know why, because first I do this
  sys->p[i] = (Particle)malloc(sizeof(Particle)) to allocate. Visual Studio says "HEAP[template.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 01E70000, 01E749B0 )
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in template.exe."

Comment: sorry for picking both C and C++. it should be C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use an asterisk when making such a typedef. This easily leads to a lot of confusion when malloc'ing memory and using pointers. Just use

```
typedef struct {
   float m;  
   float *x;  
   float *v;    
   float *f;     
   float R;
} Particle;
```

This will make it much more clear, I don't even know which behaviour your typedef causes (your probably only alloc space for a pointer)

Just take a line at those 2 lines:

```
sys->p =  (Particle *) malloc(sizeof(Particle)*noOfParticles);
sys->p[i] = (Particle)malloc(sizeof(Particle));
```

I assume you want to get memory for the pointers in the first place and than memory for the struct itself in the second. But how should this work? You use sizeof(Particle) in both mallocs.

Comment: Thanks that was it. But I thought this way it would be more efficient

Comment: One hint: If you want to typedef a pointer, use 2 typedefs: One for the struct, and one for the pointer: typedef struct { char \*string; int a; double b; } myStruct; typedef myStruct \* myStructPointer;

Answer (score 5):

It's been a while since I've done C/C++ programming, but don't those typedefs declare `Particle` to be of type pointer-to-that-struct and `ParticleSystem` to be of type pointer-to-that-other-struct?  If so, when you allocate the memory you're only allocating enough memory to hold a **pointer**, not the actual struct.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
  float m;
  float *x;
  float *v;
  float *f;
  float R;
} *Particle;

typedef struct {
  Particle *p;
  int n;
  float t;
} *ParticleSystem;

int main()
{
  cout << "sizeof(Particle) = " << sizeof(Particle) << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(ParticleSystem) = " << sizeof(ParticleSystem) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and when I run that program I get:

```
sizeof(Particle) = 4
sizeof(ParticleSystem) = 4
```

Comment: Shorthand for "C or C++ programming"

Comment: Contrary to Popular Belief™, C is not a subset of C++.

Comment: @tiftik: Nor is Python 2 a subset of Python 3.  However, treating them as father-and-son alleviates much of the confusion caused by people who insist on treating them like distant-twice-removed-cousins.

Answer (score 4):

If this is C, you really shouldn't be type-casting the return value of `malloc()`. If this is C++, you really shouldn't be using `malloc()`.

Also, I would suggest not `typedef`:ing away your pointers, it makes it much harder to follow the code and spot bugs.

Further, there's no point in using `malloc()` if you know that an array will always be of a constant small size, such as two (`Particle.f` is used this way). Just declare an array directly, and save on the `malloc()`s and associated confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
typedef struct {
float m;  
float *x;  
float *v;    
float *f;     
float R;
} *Particle;
```

to

```
typedef struct {
float m;  
float *x;  
float *v;    
float *f;     
float R;
} Particle;
```

You need to have a `Particle` in order to have a `*Particle` and in order to have `sizeof(Particle)` work...  The same goes for `ParticleSystem`

Answer (score 1):

I would start by fixing the struct declaration to:

```
} Particle;
```

and

```
} ParticleSystem;
```

instead of pointers.

And then update the rest of code to reflect this changes, beginning with:

```
ParticleSystem* sys = (ParticleSystem*) malloc(sizeof(ParticleSystem));  
sys->p =  (Particle*) malloc(sizeof(Particle) * noOfParticles);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have `Particle *p`, that you can allocate as a single Particle or an array of Particles.

You are allocating *p as an array in the second line, so you must NOT allocate them again inside the for loop, UNLESS you use `Particle **p` and then allocate *(p) as an array os POINTERS to Particle, then you alloc each particle inside the for loop. I do not recommend that.

As mentioned above, remove the pointer declaration from the structs.

And, following that you don't have to re-allocate every particle (since p is an ordinary pointer), you should free it with `free(sys->p);` only, because you're allocating each single particle as a direct place in the memory, not as pointers, as I said.

Hope it helps :)